# Cannot upload image above 75 kb

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, zend-framework

I successfully uploaded an image below 70 kb on server. manage server cpanel view already set php.ini file

```
      max_upload =2000mb 
      max-exe-time = 300  
     max input time =600
```

n php.ini file everything is ok.

My problem above 70kb image can't move temp directory
i cant understand im using zend framework and java script using

Server Error log display following error

```
[Thu Jun 20 20:53:32 2013] [error] [client 59.164.48.115] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Response_Exception' with message 'Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /home/indepet/application/modules/cms/controllers/ProductController.php, line 1' in /home/indepet/library/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:321\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/indepet/library/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(148): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)\n#1 /home/indepet/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/Redirector.php(223): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setRedirect('/index/home', 302)\n#2 /home/indepet/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/Redirector.php(301): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector->_redirect('/index/home')\n#3 /home/indepet/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/Redirector.php(381): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector->setGotoSimple('home', 'index', NULL, Array)\n#4 /home/indepet/library/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/Redirector.php(502): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector->gotoSimple('home', 'index', NULL, Array)\n#5 [internal fun in /home/indepet/library/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php on line 321, referer: my site name
```

sometimes 100 and 100 above kb image file upload successfully again 
i was try image upload following error show

another doubt 
 same code work other servers successfully im using Australia server

Comment: DAT limit O_O `2000mb`

Comment: what i cant understand

Comment: Error doesn't look like having to do anything with the file size. In fact due to the fact a file takes quite long to upload, the php already executes a part of a script and thus the headers' error is thrown. Make sure you post the code, especially the start of the script.

Comment: Have you checked that max upload size is being applied? Use ini_get('post_max_size') from your php to make sure. I'm unsure that "2000mb" is correct - it's usually "2000M"

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. If there's a problem with your original question, improve your question instead of just re-posting it. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918416/php-image-upload-errors amd http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206558/above-70-kb-image-not-upload-in-temp-directory and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208296/cannot-upload-image-above-70kb

Answer (score 0):

This error isn't related to upload size, instead Zend is trying to print headers after something has already been rendered (possibly because there's been an error and it's trying to redirect). Check for anything that may have been outputted in your view controller. White space at the end of the file is an easy one to miss - in fact, it's good practice to not use a closing PHP tag `?>` at the end of the file for this reason.